# SQL Server stored procedures to copy tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have to move a table into other table using a stored procedure by passing the table names as parameters.

Syntax is:

```
alter procedure [dbo].[moving]
(
    @to_table varchar(50),
    @from_table varchar(50)
)
as
begin
    EXEC('Select * into '+@to_table+'from '+@from_table)
end
```

while executing by.

```
exec moving newtable,hello
```

It is giving an error:

> Incorrect syntax near 'hello'

pls anyone give solution for this

Comment: Add an extra space before the 'from': `' from '`

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
exec moving 'newtable','hello'
```

It also looks like you are going to need to fix your SP. You will need a space before from:

```
EXEC('Select * into '+@to_table+' from '+@from_table)
```

Answer (score 1):

Read [EXECUTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx) syntax and try,

```
EXEC moving 'newtable','hello'
```

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT ... INTO` needs to create table, if table exists use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ..FROM`

**AND**

in your case you need to run SP in such a way:

```
EXEC dbo.moving 'table1', 'table2'
```

**BUT**

```
EXEC('Select * into '+@to_table+' from '+@from_table)
```

will not work, you need to rewrite it with variable:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
SET @sql = N'Select * into ['+@to_table+N'] from ['+@from_table+N']'
EXEC(@sql)
```

**BUT**

you also need to worry of **sql injections** and **complex table names** *AT LEAST*, so - for complex table names I already framed your tables with square braces, and you need to do something to prevent sql injections.

And once more - `SELECT...INTO` **works only if you creating new table** with name from `@to_table` parameter

Answer (score 0):

add an extra space after single quote and *FROM*

```
EXEC('Select * into ' + @to_table + ' from ' + @from_table)
```

Comment: That isn't why he is getting the error he is getting. I've already mentioned the need for a space in my answer.