# Stored procedure to copy table using dynamic query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to create a stored procedure for coping table using dynamic query.

I followed this step for creating stored proceduce, link:-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8698231/sql-server-stored-procedures-to-copy-tables

but I got an error:

> Could not find stored procedure 'Select * into tblDetail from salesDetail'

Here is my code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_copyOneTableToAnother 
    @newtable nvarchar(50),
    @oldtable nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(1000)
    SET @sql = 'SELECT * INTO ' + @newtable +
               ' FROM ' + @oldtable
    
    EXEC @sql
END

exec sp_copyOneTableToAnother @newtable='tblDetail',@oldtable='salesDetail'
```

The stored procedure was created from above syntax but while calling `sp_copyOneTableToAnother`, I get an error. Please help me solve it.

Comment: FYI the prefix `sp_` is reserved, by Microsoft, for **S**pecial / **S**ystem **P**rocedures. It should *not* be used for User Procedures. Doing so comes with a performance cost and the risk of your Procedure simply not working one day after an update/upgrade. Either use a different prefix or (possibly better) no prefix at all. [Is the sp_ prefix still a no-no?](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix)

Comment: @Larnu I changed name to 'copyOneTableToAnother' and still it threw same error

Comment: Brackets shouldn't matter, except when they do. Have you read [Using EXECUTE 'tsql_string' with a variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql#c-using-execute-tsql_string-with-a-variable) yet? Have you tried `exec (@sql)` yet?

Comment: Blargh, `EXEC (@SQL);` isn't much better, in my opinion @AlwaysLearning .

Comment: exec (@sql) worked. Problem solved

Comment: Well, this is true @Larnu.

Comment: Now just try `EXEC dbo.sp_copyOneTableToAnother N'dbo.a; CREATE LOGIN a, WITH PASSWORD '1', CHECK_POLICY = OFF; /*', N'*/ALTER SERVER ROLE sysadmin ADD MEMBER a;--` @Awesome (don't do this...).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several problems here, first, your procedure name starts with `sp_`, which is reserved by Microsoft for Special / System Procedures. That should go.

Next, your parameter types are wrong; the correct data type for an object is a `sysname`, a synonym of `nvarchar(128) NOT NULL`, *not* `varchar`.

Next, the injection issue; you *blindly* inject the values of your parameters into your statement and hope that said values aren't malicious. Validate the value of `@oldtable` and properly quote both parameters.

Finally, the execution should be done by `sp_executesql`; not using it promotes further injection issues as you can't parametrise `EXEC (@SQL)` statements.

You also don't define your schemas, which you really should be. I add them as `NULL`able parameters here, and get the `USER`'s default schema

This results in something like this:

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.CopyOneTableToAnother @NewTable sysname,
                                                    @OldTable sysname,
                                                    @NewSchema sysname = NULL,
                                                    @OldSchema sysname = NULL AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT @NewSchema = ISNULL(@NewSchema,default_schema_name),
           @OldSchema = ISNULL(@OldSchema,default_schema_name)
    FROM sys.database_principals
    WHERE name = USER_NAME();

    DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);

    SELECT @SQL = N'SELECT * INTO ' + QUOTENAME(@NewSchema) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(@NewTable) + N' FROM ' + QUOTENAME(s.[name]) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(t.[name]) + N';'
    FROM sys.schemas s
         JOIN sys.tables t ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
    WHERE s.name = @OldSchema
      AND t.[name] = @OldTable;

    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL;
END;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f0552e887054a560e9aa1b2dcf16d75a)